# condition to do something only once every x number of loops

Tags: c++, math, conditional-statements

I can't figure this out so maybe someone here can help me. I have a function with one argument and inside that function there's code I want to run every x number of times.

```
void doSomething(int _arg){
    // do something every 250 times
}
```

The function is called repeatedly but the argument isn't augmented by 1. So for example the function calls might look like this and I want a condition inside the function to be run every 250 times.

```
doSomething(1); // do something
doSomething(130);
doSomething(230);
doSomething(310); // 250 was passed, do something
doSomething(420);
doSomething(570); // 2*250 was passed, do something
```

I can't just do something like `if(_arg % 250 == 0)` because the value of `_arg` is irregular (but the intervals are always smaller than 250).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about a static variable:

```
void doSomething(int _arg){
    static int x = 0;

    if (_arg > x) {
        x += 250;  //update x to be crossed next time
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Would a better approach would be to wrap this in a class so that you remove any possible threading issues?

Comment: @MarkB You tell me, I know very little C++.

Comment: -1. `_arg > x` doesn't check for a jump of 250 or more! It should rather be `_arg >= (x + 250)`.

Comment: @cnicutar: Yes. See the question.

Comment: @Nawaz I'm not sure I understand, can you provide specific input that would be problematic ?

Comment: @cnicutar: Ohh.. you're right. I actually misread your answer. Removed downvote, and upvoted!

Comment: @Nawaz No worries, I just wanted to make sure

Answer (score 1):

You can use an extra variable, say global or static:

```
void doSomething(int _arg)
{
    static unsigned int next_target = 0;
    if (_arg >= next_target)
    {
        // do something special
        next_target = _arg - _arg % 250 + 250;  // set next_target to smallest
                                                // multiple of 250 above _arg
    }
}
```

This assumes that receiving `10` then `1002`, means, the action must take place خدمغ twice.

In case it must continue doing the action every time the function is called to catch up with `next_target`, you can do this:

```
void doSomething(int _arg)
{
    static unsigned int next_target = 0;
    if (_arg >= next_target)
    {
        // do something special
        next_target += 250;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if it should immediately take action until it catches up with `next_target`, you can do this:

```
void doSomething(int _arg)
{
    static unsigned int next_target = 0;
    while (_arg >= next_target)
    {
        // do something special
        next_target += 250;
    }
}
```